# pickerInput names and values from dataframe R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinywidgets

I'm not sure if I'm just not searching the right thing, but I'm not able to find an answer.

I have a Shiny dashboard which has a picker to subset dataframe columns.

I have another dataframe which contains two columns:

- The column name to appear in the picker choices
- The corresponding column name as it appears in the dataframe.

```
dat <- data.frame(
  names = c("CODE", "STATE_OR_PROVINCE", "LOCATION_CODE"),
  display = c("Code", "State or province", "Location code")
)
```

What I want is to simply have dat$display = dat$names in the `choices = list()` argument inside of  `pickerInput`, but that throws an error.

How can I achieve this? I know I can do it manually using:

```
          pickerInput(
            "example",
            "Example: ",
            choices = c(list("Code" = "CODE"),
                        list("State or province" = "STATE_OR_PROVINCE"),
                        list("Location code" = "LOCATION_CODE")
                        )
          )
```

But this rapidly becomes cumbersome the more choices there are.

Reproducible example:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(shinyWidgets)

dat <- data.frame(
  names = c("CODE", "STATE_OR_PROVINCE", "LOCATION_CODE"),
  display = c("Code", "State or province", "Location code")
)
ui <- fluidPage(


    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          pickerInput(
            "example",
            "Example: ",
            choices = c(list("Code" = "CODE"),
                        list("State or province" = "STATE_OR_PROVINCE"),
                        list("Location code" = "LOCATION_CODE")
                        )
          )
        ),
        mainPanel()
    )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  observe({
    input$example %>% glimpse()
  })
   
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a named vector for the `choices` argument:

```
choices_data <- dat$names
names(choices_data) <- dat$display
```

```
pickerInput(
        "example",
        "Example: ",
        choices = choices_data
      )
```